# python sending goals to the navigation stack

Tags: python, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any good examples on how to send goals to the navigation stack in python? I been looking around and yet to find the equivalent of the example shown in the navigation tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80646/python-sending-goals-to-the-navigation-stack/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just a matter of making a action call. There is an [actionlib tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20%28Python%29) showing how to make an action call with python. For navigation, all you have to do is substitute the appropriate goal type.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VickyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/32904/vickyd/) on 2018-01-09**:
The link is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Hoping it can be helpful to someone, I have wrote two posts about sending goals to the navigation stack with a Python node (with example code):

- Sending a single goal (equivalent to the C++ tutorial), [here](https://github.com/HotBlackRobotics/hotblackrobotics.github.io/blob/master/en/blog/_posts/2018-01-29-action-client-py.md).
- Sending a sequence of goals (complete of simulation with a turtlebot robot), [here](https://github.com/HotBlackRobotics/hotblackrobotics.github.io/blob/master/en/blog/_posts/2018-01-29-seq-goals-py.md).

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [fiorellasibona](https://answers.ros.org/users/33559/fiorellasibona/) with karma: 131 on 2018-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-26**:
Can you please update your answer with more information including code examples that way it will be self-contained? If those pages move or disappear then this answer will be useless.

**Comment by [LeGer](https://answers.ros.org/users/39796/leger/) on 2019-02-01**:
thanks for the code. When I run the code I get the error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SimpleActionClient'
I also tried import SimpleActionClient from actionlib -> doesn't work either. Does anybody have an idea?

**Comment by [fiorellasibona](https://answers.ros.org/users/33559/fiorellasibona/) on 2019-03-04**:
Hi @jayess, I have updated my answer, thank you!

**Comment by [fiorellasibona](https://answers.ros.org/users/33559/fiorellasibona/) on 2019-03-04**:
Hi @LeGer, due to changes to the turtlebot launch files names the code started returning the error you have reported. The code has been updated and now should work fine. Don't hesitate to contact me for any further issue!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-04**:
@fiorellasibona sorry for the confusion, but I meant putting the examples *in the answer*. The reason is to keep answers self-contained because files/pages can and do disappear from other sites making the answers not helpful